# How to give html tags inside string interpolation in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, string-interpolation

I have

```
const getConfirmMsg= (card, isDelete) => {
       const valueType = getValue(card);
    
        const confirmMessage = isDelete ? (
              `You are about to delete the ${valueType}.This is the last value.`
          ) : (
            `All selected values will be removed.`
          );

return (
tr(confirmMessage, {valueType}
);}
```

I want ${valueType} as itallic font and a line break before the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this and the translation are working fine now. Because I am working on multilingual app. Translations are needed.

```
const getConfirmMsg= (card, isDelete) => {
       const valueType = getValue(card);
    
        const confirmMessage = isDelete ? (
              <>
              <p>{tr(`You are about to delete the`)} <i>{tr( valueType)}</i> .
              </p>
              <p>{tr(` This is the last value.`)}</p>
              </>
          ) : (
            tr(`All selected values will be removed.`)
          );

return (confirmMessage);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const confirmMessage = isDelete ? (
  <p>
    You are about to delete the <em>{valueType}</em>.
    <br />
    This is the last value.
  </p>
  ) : (
    `All selected values will be removed.`
  );
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but tr wont work for this HTML content. I have edited the question with more clarity.

Comment: What is `tr(confirmMessage, {valueType})` ?

Comment: tr is the translation, i am returning the message inside tr.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tr/v/1.1.4

I will be using getConfirmMsg to pass the value at required function

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but if you need to render html tags inside a string you will need a markdown library, of which I would suggest `react-html-parser`.

Usage:

```js
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

ReactHtmlParser(`You are about to delete the ${valueType}.This is the last value.`)
```